# Simple series divergence problem

Tags: limits, divergent-series

I've got a problem here:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{5^n}{n(3^{n+1})}$$

I've used the ratio test and essentially did this:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{5^{n + 1}}{n (3^{n+1+1})} / \frac{5^n}{n(3^{n+1})}\right) = \frac{5^n\,5}{9(n+1)3^n} \cdot \frac{n\,3^n}{5^n}$$

With a bunch of cancellations we get $\dfrac{5n}{9n+9}$, which means it converges, as $\frac{5}{9} < 1$. But the answer says it diverges! I even tried the root test and got the same result. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The cancellations are not done correctly. Where you have $9$ one should have $3$.

Comment: The limit of the inside terms do not go to zero.

Comment: That summation sign before the nasty fraction shouldn't be there. It's difficult to tell if this is where you are going wrong, because your algebra is wrong in any case!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
  a_n &= \frac{5^n}{n(3^{n+1})} \\[2em]
  \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}
  &= \frac{5^{n+1}}{(n+1)(3^{n+2})} / \frac{5^n}{n(3^{n+1})} \\[0.5em]
  &= \frac{5^{n+1} \cdot n \cdot 3^{n+1}}{5^n \cdot (n+1) \cdot 3^{n+2}} \\[0.5em]
  &= \frac{5}{3} \left( \frac{n}{n+1} \right) \\[0.5em]
  &= \frac{5}{3} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{n+1} \right) \\[0.5em]
  &\to \frac{5}{3}>1
\end{align}$$

Therefore, from the ratio test,we conclude that the series diverges.

Comment: Oh my dear lord I missed a 3. I've been struggling with this for awhile. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\dfrac{5^n}{n3^{n+1}} > \dfrac{1}{n}$ for $n > 2$